# C# Weird issue with BinaryFormatter serialize/deserialize

Tags: c#, binaryformatter

I'm currently having a VERY weird issue with BinaryFormatter serialize / deserialize i hope i can get some help with.

Right now, i'm currently working on learning Game Development with Unity 5.5 for the last 2 months. I decided to challenge myself and create a multiplayer game in which i've created the network part all by myself.

Around a week ago, i tested it over the internet with a friend and all was working as expected, but yesterday i found a problem which is making it unplayable.

```
[Serializable]
public class Packet
{
    //Remeber to change Packet function if changing something here
    public List<string> Gdata;
    public int PacketInt;
    public bool PacketBool;
    public string senderID;
    public PacketType packetType;

    public Packet(PacketType type, string senderID)
    {
        Gdata = new List<string>();
        this.senderID = senderID;
        this.packetType = type;
    }

    public Packet(byte[] packetBytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(packetBytes);

        Console.WriteLine(packetBytes);

        Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        ms.Close();
        this.Gdata = p.Gdata;
        this.PacketInt = p.PacketInt;
        this.PacketBool = p.PacketBool;
        this.senderID = p.senderID;
        this.packetType = p.packetType;
    }

    public byte[] ToBytes()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        bf.Serialize(ms, this);

        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();
        return bytes;
    }

    public static string GetIP4Address()
    {
        IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        foreach (IPAddress i in ips)
        {
            if (i.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                return i.ToString();
        }

        return "127.0.0.1";
    }
}

public enum PacketType
{
    /* Connection */
    Connecting,
    Handshake,
    ConnectionComfirmed,
    DataRequest,
    NewClient, // Sent from the server to all players online when a new player has connected, containing revelant data to sync the new player.
    Disconnecting,

    /* Errors */
    ServerError,

    /* Updates */
    Movement,
    PositionUpdate,

    /* Chat */
    Chat
}
```

The problem i'm describing below happends on the line ***Packet p = (Packet)bf.Deserialize(ms);***

This is what i'm using to handle the packets. It's inside a DLL which i have attached to both the server software and the game i'm creating. An example on how it works is this:

```
void DataManager(Packet p)
{
    switch (p.packetType)
    {
        case PacketType.Connecting:
            if (p.Gdata[1] == ServerHandshake)
            {
                _clientID = p.senderID;

                Packet sp = new Packet(PacketType.Handshake, _clientID);
                sp.Gdata.Add(ClientHandshake);
                _socket.Send(sp.ToBytes());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

When testing it locally, it's working without a problem and has been working fine for the last 2 months. Also, as i wrote above, i tested it a little over a week ago without a problem what so ever.

However, the problem now is that for some reason, at the exact same moment, i get the error 'The input stream is not a valid binary format' whenever someone connected over the internet is moving. The code for this part is below:

```
if (movement_vector != Vector2.zero)
        {
            anim.SetBool("iswalking", true);
            anim.SetFloat("input_x", movement_vector.x);
            anim.SetFloat("input_y", movement_vector.y);

            Packet p = new Packet(PacketType.Movement, GetComponent<Script_PlayerData>().Player_GUID);
            p.Gdata.Add(movement_vector.x.ToString());
            p.Gdata.Add(movement_vector.y.ToString());
            p.Gdata.Add(player.position.x.ToString());
            p.Gdata.Add(player.position.y.ToString());
            GameObject.Find("GameScripts").GetComponent<Script_Network>()._socket.Send(p.ToBytes());
            if (HasMoved == 0) HasMoved = 1;
        }
```

Before this part is even executed, the server and game client is sending several packets back and forth, and that is working completly fine. Even the chat i've added to the game is working as intended but as soon as a player connected over the internet is moving to any direction, i get the ***'The input stream is not a valid binary format'*** exception thrown, even though it's working fine locally with atleast up to 10 clients connected.

I've been looking around on the internet for hours trying to find a solution to this issue but nothing i've tested or read so far has been working for me.

I haven't modified this code at all since the first time i tested it with remote players connected. I also update the DLL in the Unity project every time after i have compiled the DLL.

So as a last resort, i'm asking here. Anyone knows what possibly could make it behave like this, and does anyone knows a solution to it?

EDIT: Apparently forgot to specify it's TCP. Code Snippets below that might help you understand better how it works:

Server Program:

```
    void SetupSocket()
    {
        ConsoleMessage("Initializing socket...");
        _listenerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(s_config.ServerIP), s_config.ServerPort);

        ConsoleMessage("Binding server to " + s_config.ServerIP + ":" + s_config.ServerPort);

        _listenerSocket.Bind(ip);
        _listenerThread = new Thread(ListenThread);
        _listenerThread.Start();
    }

    void NetworkListener(Socket _socket, string GUID) // Threaded for each client connected
    {
        OnlinePlayers++;

        byte[] Buffer;
        int readBytes;
        try
        {

            for (;;)
            {
                int l = GetPlayerIndexSlot(GUID);
                if (l == -1) break;

                Buffer = new byte[_socket.SendBufferSize];

                readBytes = _socket.Receive(Buffer);

                if (readBytes > 0)
                {
                    Packet packet = new Packet(Buffer);
                    DataManager(_socket, packet);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ConsoleMessage("Socket error: " + ex.ErrorCode + ", Client id: " + GUID);
            if (ex.ErrorCode == 10054) // WSAECONNRESET - Connection reset by peer
            {
                OnPlayerDisconnecting(_socket, 5);
            }
        }
    }

    void DataManager(Socket _socket, Packet p)
    {
        switch (p.packetType)
        {
            case PacketType.Connecting:     ConnectingPacket(_socket, p.Gdata[0]);                                                  break;
            case PacketType.Handshake:      HandshakeProcess(p.senderID, _socket, p.Gdata[0]);                                      break;
            case PacketType.Disconnecting:  OnPlayerDisconnecting(_socket, 0);                                                      break;
            case PacketType.DataRequest:    DataRequest(p.Gdata[0], _socket, p.senderID);                                           break;
            case PacketType.Movement:       PlayerMovement(p.senderID, _socket, p.Gdata[0], p.Gdata[1], p.Gdata[2], p.Gdata[3]);    break;
            case PacketType.PositionUpdate: PlayerPositionUpdate(p.senderID, _socket, p.Gdata[0], p.Gdata[1]);                      break;
            case PacketType.Chat:           ChatMessage(p.senderID, _socket, p.Gdata[0]);                                           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The socket type is not obvious and the receiver code is missing.  If it is UDP then the probable issue is that the packet is too large to fit the MTU of the connection.  If it is TCP then the issue is that the receiver cannot reliably read the packet because it doesn't know how many bytes to read.

Comment: My bad, i have updated the bottom of the post. I hope that is enough.

Comment: Hopefully you can see why new byte[_socket.SendBufferSize] is nonsensical.  Plain problem is that you have no idea what the value of *readBytes* should be.  It is only the size of the packet by accident.  You have to transmit the packet size first so the reader knows.

Comment: I followed what you suggested and i created a function that is sending a packet first with the size of the real packet. However, now i receive a ***The end of the data stream was found before the parsing was completed*** exception and i comfirmed it. The original packet was 547 bytes according to Unity but on the server, it was 539.. Looks like i need to do some more digging to solve this.